# ViewPager vanishes after getting back to the containing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity which have a complex structure of Fragments. The Activity have two containers, each for a NavigationDrawerFragment and a Main Content Fragment(HomeTabFragment). The Main Content Fragment has TabLayout+ViewPager structure containing two child Fragments(Search and News). This has been working well, untill I need to replace Main Content Fragment with another Fragment (Settings). This also worked well, but when I want to get back to the same Main Content Fragment, the ViewPager, along with the child fragments vanishes.

This is structure. HomeTabFragment is replaced by SettingsFragment via a button (In LeftDrawerFragment) and SettingsFragment is again replaced by HomeTabFragment via a button (In LeftDrawerFragment or a hardware back key)

```
HomeActivity
 |-LeftDrawerFragment
 |-HomeTabFragment
 | |-ViewPager
 |   |-HomeSearchFragment
 |   |-HomeNewsFragment
 |-SettingsFragment
```

Here's the HomeActivity layout -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_home"/>-->
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!--Toolbar-->
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:subtitle="Your Medi-buddy"
                    app:title="@string/app_name">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:onClick="onHomeMenuClick"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/app_name"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Large" />
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
            <!-- The main content view -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_frag_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer_container"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#111" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Following is the layout of my HomeTabFragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:tabBackground="@android:color/white"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is how I am changing back and forth between HomeTabFragment and SettingsFragment

```
public void onLeftDrawerSettingsClick(View view) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.tab_frag_container, mApp.getFragmentController().getSettingsFragment()).addToBackStack("Drawer").commit();
    }

    public void onLeftDrawerHomeClick(View view) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.tab_frag_container, mApp.getFragmentController().getHomeTabFragment()).commit();
    }
```

I am unable to understand why the ViewPager is getting affected by the replace transaction. I found out that it has something to do with not allowing Child fragments in API Level 15 or lower, however this has been fixed in the latest support library and I don't think it can be an issue.

Is there any way I can replace the HomeTabFragment with SettingsFragment and vice-versa, without affecting the other functionalities? Or is it something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution was to not create the complete view of the fragment when it loads the second time. For that I put following code in the `onCreateView()` of `HomeTabFragment`

```
if (mParent != null)
    return mParent;
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
mParent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_tab, container, false);
```

Though the solution works, but I am still unable to explain why is it happening? Posting it as an answer, in case someone is looking for a solution. Please provide a better solution with explanation, if you can.